# Safe user template system

Tags: 7

Is there a template system for users that would be very safe, and very simple? I'm looking for something along the lines of the following:

> Hello [first_name],
>
> We hope you have enjoyed the
>   [product.name] purchased on
>   [transaction.date] for
>   [product.price].

I realize this is kind of a contrived example, but what I'm looking to do is give users the ability to customize some information but not give them PHP as that would be out of control.

I would use a filter editor, but I need to provide the context for the variables and I'm not sure how much it would complicate matters to have to provide that context, (which could not be done from a filters standpoint so far as I know because I'm providing one template for many nodes)

Comment: To which Drupal version are you interested?

Comment: Ah, I probably should have tagged that - drupal 6 would be best, but the answers I've got are very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some modules that implement an input filter which allows you to decide which text is replaced in the body of the node and with which text needs to be replaced.

- [Custom filter](http://drupal.org/project/customfilter) allows the administrator users to define, through regular expressions, which text is replaced and, through a string or PHP code, the replacement text. Normal users cannot decide neither which strings to replace nor the replacement strings; this means that they cannot do anything bad by creating a replacement rule using unsafe PHP code.
- [Regex Filters](http://drupal.org/project/regex_filter) is a module with similar features.
- [Rep[lacement]Tags](http://drupal.org/project/reptag) allows you to define tokens like `{AUTHOR}` which will be replaced.
- [Token Filter](http://drupal.org/project/token_filter) replaces, for example, text like `[token user <token>]` with the content of the user token implemented by a module. This module requires [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token).

Answer (score 3):

You want http://drupal.org/project/token

There are also modules which allow to use tokens in nodes and other places, you can use it in custom places and also define your own tokens.

The token API is even part of Drupal 7 core.